# Rendering Model.Navigation in another shape

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9

I moved some of my html from layout.cshtml to another file (topnavigation.cshtml) and called it via: @Display.TopNavigation(); In that new shape file, how can I get it to render the actual contents of the navigation zone. I expected @Display(Model.Navigation) would work but .Navigation is null when in topnavigation.cshtml?

Comment: @Display.TopNavigation(Nav: Model.Navigation) or something along those lines should work.

Then inside your shape you can call this.Model.Nav again.

Comment: The layout and zones themselves are also shapes, so adjusting `Layout.cshtml` is really just the same as overriding the template for any other shape. Inside `Layout.cshtml`, `Model` refers to the Layout shape, which contains the Navigation zone, but inside `topnavigation.cshtml` it refers to your TopNavigation shape, which has no idea what Navigation is.

I think what you want to do is `@Display(WorkContext.Layout.Navigation)`

Answer (score 4):

You are in a different shape - unless you set your `Navigation` property (eg. by calling `@Display.TopNavigation(Navigation: "something"))` it will be null, which is expected.

You can access the root `Layout` shape in any .cshtml file via `Layout` property (or `WorkContext.Layout` - both return the same object). So rendering the main navigation would be as simple as calling `@Display(Layout.Navigation)`.